# Spring layers confusion

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am new to Spring and Hibernate. I am actually facing problems defining the layers of my application which is to create a movie site where one can search movies,theaters,search movies by theater names and theaters by movie name.I summing up my queries as follows :-

1. What could be the entities in my application, I have created MovieEntity and TheaterEntity so far, how to proceed with the mappings between two.
2. My project structure should be something like this:
   Entities, repositories and services. I am not sure where to fit my service layer, as all the methods I need to implement are defined in entities.

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, and therefore you will not find one definitive answer to your question.  (I didn't downvote you, but I suspect that this is the reason for it.)

I would recommend looking at various open source projects (check github) and see how this is done by convention.

One popular way is to create DAO interfaces as a point of access to your data layer and create implementations of those DAOs that are specific to Hibernate.  Your services would contain business logic and can use Spring autowiring to link to these interfaces.  Your controllers shouldn't contain business logic and should really just route requests.  Keep your validation code separate whenever possible too.  Doing so makes it particularly easy to unit test.